# Referencing outlet not showing up in xcode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to write my first hello world in xcode. I have two labels and two buttons in my view, and my AppDelegate.h file is like this:

```
@interface QuizAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
    int currentQuestionIndex;
    // The model objects
    NSMutableArray *questions;
    NSMutableArray *answers;
    // The view objects
    IBOutlet UILabel *questionField;
    IBOutlet UILabel *answerField;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
- (IBAction)showQuestion:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)showAnswer:(id)sender;
@end
```

Now i am trying to add reference to my label. I go to LaunchScreen.xib and right click on the label. According to the tutorial, i have to see "answerField" and "questionField" under the "Outlets" tab, but nothing shows up. Can anyone tell me why this can be happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

1) That code should really be in a view controller and not the application delegate

2) You probably should be looking in the `Main.storyboard` file and not `LaunchScreen.xib`

3) Make sure that File's Owner is set to the correct view controller on `Main.storyboard` after you move that code into a view controller.